# Is it possible for ArrayList to fail in a single-writer-multi-reader system?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

I have a `List` that needs to called by multiple threads. There will be only a single writer, and this writer will add elements and do nothing else. Elements are never removed or modified. Many concurrent reader threads will call `list.size()` and `list.get(index)`.

We must assume that on occasion the internal array will need to grow as elements are added.

Can I get away with using a plain `ArrayList`, or do I need to implement some fancy concurrent structure to avoid exceptions?

Comment: "Fancy concurrent structure"... There's a [`ReadWriteLock`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/ReadWriteLock.html) so it's close to trivial to implement.

Comment: Is object mutated? Tick. Is it accessed by multiple threads? Tick. Does the object come with any thread safety guarantees? No. Congratulations, you need some kind of synchronization! The checklist really is that simple.

Comment: Do you care about the insertion order?

Comment: Yes, insertion order matters.

Answer (score 3):

If your readers all need to be reading the same state of the `List`, meaning that the writer can't write between all readers reading, then yes, you'll need to use `ReadWriteLock` or some more complex method of handling this case.

If you're not spared for memory usage, don't mind if your readers always have the most current data available, and your only goal is just to avoid exceptions, consider a `CopyOnWriteArrayList`, which is built to avoid exceptions on write/iteration conflicts. When you write to this `List`, it makes a new one as the finished result but the readers currently using the `List` continue reading the "old" (pre-write) one instead.

Comment: I would use a different set of criteria to decide: with `CopyOnWriteArrayList`, adding an element is pretty expensive, and it gets more expensive the more elements you have (because you need to copy the entire backing array to a new location every time), while `size()` and `get()` are dirt cheap. While with "regular" concurrent structures the extra cost is spread out between `add()`, 'size()` and 'get()`. So if your list is rarely modified but queried a lot, go for copy-on-write. Otherwise don't.

Comment: @biziclop nice summary, I should have included that. It's a very important point that `CopyOnWriteArrayList` is best for situations where you rarely write and often read.

Comment: Yup, you're right, will need a lock or a copy-on-write scheme. This analysis suggests that when there is only one writer plain old synchronization works pretty well: http://blog.takipi.com/java-8-stampedlocks-vs-readwritelocks-and-synchronized/

Answer (score 2):

So first off the documentation for ArrayList says it's not thread safe- so I wouldn't recommend using it in such a case. Furthermore even if this did theoretically work you'd have the problem of ensuring that whoever maintains this program remembered the strict constraints you've imposed on reading and writing with hilarity ensuing if they didn't! That said, your question is really interesting from a theoretical perspective so I thought I'd take a look.

The first thing to note is that any of the readers tried to access the list through an iterator then sooner or later the read would fail with a ConcurrentModificationException.  That's because every modification to the list is tracked and the Iterator fails fast if it detects a modification outside the iterator.

That said, you don't specify the need to use iterators in your original question so what happens if you restrict yourself to simply appending by add and reading by get() and size()?  In this case I still think you might see the occasional failure because internally the list stores the current size along with the backing data array and neither variable is marked as volatile.  As a result (and due to Java's Memory guarantees) I would think it theoretically possible for one of the reader threads to see an updated size variable while the data still hasn't been updated.  In this case you could end up junk data being returned or even an indexOutOfBounds.

Comment: Yes, precisely. The JVM can reorder instructions and yield the exact problem you describe.

Answer (score 1):

If you're open to using a third-party library, [Eclipse Collections](https://www.eclipse.org/collections/) has a type called [`MultiReaderFastList`](https://github.com/eclipse/eclipse-collections/blob/master/eclipse-collections/src/main/java/org/eclipse/collections/impl/list/mutable/MultiReaderFastList.java) which supports multiple readers and a single writer.  It throws on `iterator`.  If you need to iterate, look to use one of the many internal iteration methods, that will safely acquire a read lock and release it once iteration is complete.  If you need to write imperative iteration code, there are two methods named `withReadLockAndDelegate` and `withWriteLockAndDelegate` that will allow you to use an `iterator` safely locking before and after your block of code.

Note: I am a committer for [Eclipse Collections](https://www.eclipse.org/collections/).

Answer (score -1):

My suggestion is to use semaphores to avoid any exception, in that way you can control which reader is reading the list at any moment

Comment: Semaphores doesn't seem to be the right choice here. I'd go with a [`ReadWriteLock`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/ReadWriteLock.html).